# Failed creating tables using spring boot quartz

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am using JDBCjobstore to save the scheduler details.

Here is the configuration class and quartz properties which I am using.

## Quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=spring-boot-quartz-demo
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
```

## Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

public class AutowireCapableBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory {

    private final AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    public AutowireCapableBeanJobFactory(AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        Assert.notNull(beanFactory, "Bean factory must not be null");
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        Object jobInstance = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        this.beanFactory.autowireBean(jobInstance);
        this.beanFactory.initializeBean(jobInstance, null);
        return jobInstance;
    }
}

@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    schedulerFactoryBean.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    schedulerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    schedulerFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(
            new AutowireCapableBeanJobFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()));
    return schedulerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public Scheduler scheduler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory(applicationContext).getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    return scheduler;
}
```

}

I am getting the following exception when I am trying to run the application

```
    Position: 15
    
    org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failure identifying failed instances when checking-in: ERROR: relation "qrtz_scheduler_state" does not exist
      Position: 15
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.findFailedInstances(JobStoreSupport.java:3405) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.clusterCheckIn(JobStoreSupport.java:3455) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3315) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3920) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3957) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_scheduler_state" does not exist
      Position: 15
                    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
                    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectSchedulerStateRecords(StdJDBCDelegate.java:2994) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.findFailedInstances(JobStoreSupport.java:3369) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                    ... 4 common frames omitted
    
    2019-03-28 09:49:03.539 ERROR 15320 --- [_MisfireHandler] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : MisfireHandler: Error handling misfires: Database error recovering from misfires.
    
    org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Database error recovering from misfires.
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3259) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3997) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:4018) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_triggers" does not exist
      Position: 33
                    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_triggers" does not exist
  Position: 33
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
                at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.countMisfiredTriggersInState(StdJDBCDelegate.java:393) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3238) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                ... 2 common frames omitted

2019-03-28 09:49:09.668 ERROR 15320 --- [SchedulerThread] org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger              : An error occurred while scanning for the next triggers to fire.

org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: ERROR: relation "qrtz_triggers" does not exist
  Position: 67
                at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2910) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$41.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2805) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$41.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2803) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3849) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2802) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
                at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:287) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
```

However there is no issue if I create the tables first and then execute the application

Comment: It seems table relations are broken or tables not created properly. Can you check them ?

Answer (score 1):

Please add property in spring properties file and check

spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always